# How to access a file stored in SharePoint Document library which is Public CDN

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I have a sharepoint document library.I have made this library as Public CDN.
This library contains some files.

Now i m trying to access the files inside SPFX but it doesnt work ?
image

I am getting cors error ?
image

This is strange , i should be able to pull file from public CDN directly ?

Comment: the images didn't make it through, can you update your post? Can you also provide how you're trying to access it?

Comment: Actual problem is only for json file..rest extension work fine.So to solve the problem i converted json to txt

Comment: You should add that comment as answer and Mark it as answered. It will help others having the same issue